# Navigation Drawer переключение layout'ов

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте!
Пытаюсь кастомизировать "Navigation Drawer", чтобы при нажатии на каждый item, открывался свой layout, а лучше даже активити. Никак не могу справиться с этой задачей. Делаю по примеру: 
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/creating-side-menu-navigation-drawer-in-android/

Есть главная активити  и 2 фрагмент активити со своими layout
В методе setOnItemClickListener ( что в MainActivity) следующий код:

```
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                View view,
                                int position,
                                long id) {

            // Getting an array of rivers
            String[] rivers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Категории);

            //Currently selected river
            mTitle = rivers[position];

            // Creating a fragment object
            BlankFragment rFragment = new BlankFragment();

            // Creating a Bundle object
            Bundle data = new Bundle();

            // Setting the index of the currently selected item of mDrawerList
            data.putInt("position", position);

            // Setting the position to the fragment
            rFragment.setArguments(data);

            // Getting reference to the FragmentManager
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

            // Creating a fragment transaction
            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            // Adding a fragment to the fragment transaction
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, rFragment);

            // Committing the transaction
            ft.commit();

            // Closing the drawer
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
    });

}
```

Что нужно изменить? 
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Что не работает? Если ошибка, то кусок лога вставьте. Как по-вашему на ваш вопрос можно ответить? Скопировать пример кода из вашей же ссылки?

Comment: Видимо мной не корректно задан вопрос, чтож буду читься это делать.
По делу, я не знаю способа как перейти на дргой фрагмент.
В примере есть лэйаут фрагмента с текст вью, при нажатии на элементы бокового меню лэйаут не меняется, меняется только содержание текст вью. Каким методом вызвать дргой лэйаут?
Конкретно в этом коде ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, rFragment); фрагмент менеджер в вставляет некий фрагмент rFragment, но не тот лэйаут в котором мой фрагмент.

Comment: Активити переключить можно Intent'oм, лэйаут setContentView, но как фрагменты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите код еще раз внимательнее.
Вы создаете новый фрагмент.

```
           // Creating a fragment object
            BlankFragment rFragment = new BlankFragment();
```

Далее вы в фрагмент передаете аргумент с числом.

```
            // Creating a Bundle object
            Bundle data = new Bundle();

            // Setting the index of the currently selected item of mDrawerList
            data.putInt("position", position);

            // Setting the position to the fragment
            rFragment.setArguments(data);
```

Потом вы заменяете существующий фрагмент на новый.

```
            // Adding a fragment to the fragment transaction
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, rFragment);
```

Соответственно в новом фрагменте из аргумента берется новое число, создается новый layout для этого фрагмента и отображается на экране.

Если вы хотите вставить другой фрагмент, то создавайте его в зависимости от номера выбранного айтема.

```
           // Creating a fragment object
           Fragment f;
           if(position == 1){
              f = new BlankFragment();
           } else {
              f = new MyFragment();
           }
```

Comment: Делал именно по этому примеру, все заработало после того, как внимательно почитал logCat, нужно было удалить строки 


               // Retrieving the currently selected item number
        int position = getArguments().getInt("position");