# Android Navigation Drawer - Как вставить ListView в Fragment?

Tags: android, java

Android Navigation Drawer - Как вставить ListView в Fragment?
Скачал готовый проект отсюда:
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#ListItemClicks
Разобрался, где отслеживать клик на элемент в сайтбаре, но, по умолчанию меняется картинка у контента. Мне же нужно делать POST запрос, и строить listview. Как быть в таком случае?

Comment: Разбейте задачу на несколько этапов и задайте вопрос отдельно по каждому. Я ничего не понял из этой каши.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала нужно сделать фрагмент в котором код будет выполняться. Наверное в фоне будет POST запрос.
По нажатию запускайте фрагмент. У меня была такая же проблема)
[Тут обсуждали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/311693/java-navigation-drawer-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-layout-%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: По сути пишете в методе onItemClick пишете:

        Fragment f;
                if(position == 0){

                    f = new MyCompanyFragment();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, f);
                    ft.commit();

                } if (position==1) {

Comment: Подожди)))
MyCompanyFragment - это твой класс который ты создал?
Какой файл нужно мне создать в лейаутах, для того чтобы вставить в один экран кнопку (по которой вызывается дейтпикер) и листВью?

Comment: Тебе нужно создать фрагмент ( Получается это класс, у которого есть лейаут). В этом лейауте сделаешь какой надо интерфейс. Например лист вью или что угодно.
Далее, в классе который отвечает за боковое меню, в методе он клик пишешь код, который я тебе написал. 
В своем фрагменте нужно будет написать вместо:

         setContentView(R.layout.main-например);
****
         View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.тот_лэйаут_который_хочешь_чтобы_тут_был, container, false);

Comment: Сделал всё как ты сказал, приложение теперь вылетает (

Comment: Вот немного ошибок:

04-22 11:10:02.535: E/AndroidRuntime(25098): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 11:10:02.535: E/AndroidRuntime(25098): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample/com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.InboxActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample.InboxActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Comment: Разобрался, в чём была ошибка. Твой код помог мне. Спасибо большое!